# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getValue() from the type SelectOption

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<SelectOption> ObjectNames()
{
    system.debug('object is calling:::');
   List<SelectOption> ObjNames= new List<SelectOption>();
    ObjNames.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
    ObjNames.add(new selectoption('Pay_Element_Master__c','Pay Element'));
    ObjNames.add(new selectoption('CTC_Master__c','CTC Master'));
    ObjNames.add(new selectoption('Section_Master__c','Section Master'));
    return ObjNames;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static  List < SelectOption >  getComponent(string wrapval,string id) {
     String objectName;
    Criteria_Master__c cmas = new Criteria_Master__c();
    List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = (List < WrapperCriteria > ) JSON.deserialize(wrapval, List<WrapperCriteria >.class);
    system.debug('::::::wrList value::::' + warpList);
    system.debug('id value ::::::' + id);
    WrapperCriteria ac=new WrapperCriteria ();
    List < SelectOption > ObjNames = new List < SelectOption > ();
    ObjNames.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
    ObjNames.add(new selectoption('Pay_Element_Master__c', 'Pay Element'));
    ObjNames.add(new selectoption('CTC_Master__c', 'CTC Master'));

    Map <String,String> ctcMasAPINames = new Map < String, String > ();
    WrapperCriteria dc = new  WrapperCriteria();
    dc.componentMap = new Map<String, String>();
    dc.componentMap1 = new Map<String, String>();
    cmas = [select id, Name, Action_Criteria__c, Company_Master__c from Criteria_Master__c where Id=:id];

    if (warpList.size() > 0) {
        for (WrapperCriteria wr: warpList) {
            List <SelectOption > options = new List <SelectOption > ();
            if (wr.ObjectApiNAme == 'Pay_Element_Master__c') {
                for (SelectOption so: ObjNames) {
                    if (so.getValue() == wr.ObjectApiNAme) {
                        objectName = so.getLabel();
                        system.debug('****objectname *****' + objectName);
                    }
                }
                wr.SelObjectName = objectName;     //aassigned to wrapper


                for (Pay_Element_Master__c pem: [select id, name, Company_Master__c from Pay_Element_Master__c where Company_Master__c = : cmas.Company_Master__c]) {
                    options.add(new SelectOption(pem.id, pem.name));
                     dc.componentMap.put(pem.id,pem.name);
                    ctcMasAPINames.put(pem.id, pem.name);
                    System.debug('--------Pay element MAster MAP VAlues-----' + ctcMasAPINames);
                }
                //ac.Components = options;

            } 
            else if (wr.ObjectApiNAme == 'CTC_Master__c') {
                for (SelectOption so: ObjNames) {
                    if (so.getValue() == wr.ObjectApiNAme) {
                        objectName = so.getLabel();
                        system.debug('-----------objectname --------------' + objectName);
                    }
                }
                wr.SelObjectName = objectName;
                Map < String, Schema.SObjectType > globalDescription = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
                Schema.sObjectType objType = globalDescription.get('CTC_Master__c');
                Schema.DescribeSObjectResult ob = objType.getDescribe();

                if (ob == Null) {
                    AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException('Invalid sObject Type');
                    e.setMessage('Invalid sObject Type');
                    system.debug(e);
                    throw e;

                }
                Map < String, Schema.SObjectField > mapFieldList = ob.fields.getMap();

                for (Schema.SObjectField field: mapFieldList.values()) {
                    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = field.getDescribe();
                    if (fieldResult.isAccessible() && (fieldResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Integer || fieldResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Double || fieldResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Currency)) {
                        options.add(new SelectOption(fieldResult.getName(), fieldResult.getLabel()));
                         dc.componentMap1.put(fieldResult.getName(),fieldResult.getLabel());
                        ctcMasAPINames.put(fieldResult.getName(),fieldResult.getLabel());   
                    }
                }
                //ac.Components1= options;
                //system.debug('components1 value ::::::'+ ac.Components1);
            }
        }
    }
    system.debug('dc  value ::::::'+dc);
    return dc;
  }


   public class SelectOption {

   public SelectOption(String value, String label) {
    this.value = value;
    this.label = label;
    this.disabled = false;
    this.escapeItem = false;
   }

   public SelectOption(String value, String label, Boolean isDisabled) {
    this.value = value;
    this.label = label;
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
    this.escapeItem = false;
   }

  @AuraEnabled
  public String label { get;set; }
  @AuraEnabled
  public String value { get;set; }
  @AuraEnabled
  public Boolean disabled { get;set; }
  @AuraEnabled
  public Boolean escapeItem { get;set; }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no method called getValue in your custom class called SelectOption. If you were using the standard class, such a method would exist, or if you'd written a method like that, it would exist. Instead, you can just access value directly:

```
if (so.value == wr.ObjectApiNAme) {
```